# Netbeans & GlassFish Server 3.1.2

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, java

I try to run my project using netbeans but I keep getting this message !

> **Unable to start the GlassFish Server 3.1.2 server. GlassFish Server 3 requires the JDK 6 platform. To run GlassFish Server 3, you need to specify the location of the JDK 6 executable in the Servers manager**

How to  specify the location of the JDK 6???

can someone help ?

Comment: Thanx all , It is solved

Comment: in case anyone face this error , I found the server manager under the services tag . follow this path : services -> servers -> Glassfish server --> Java , then you can specify the exe file

Comment: You can put your solution as an answer. Later when the system permits, you can accept the answer.